# How overloaded horzcat() works?

Tags: oop, matlab, overloading

I'm writing a Matlab class that implements custom concatenation in order to present a clean, expressive interface to the user. Unlike the built-in's, the result of the overloaded `horzcat()` --- for example --- should be a scalar object set according to class' semantics. However, I'm not sure anymore about which rules apply to overloaded functions...

A class to illustrate the issue would be:

```
classdef A < handle
        properties
                k;
        end;

        methods
                function obj = A(varargin)
                        if nargin == 0
                                obj.k = 0;
                        else
                                obj.k = varargin{1};
                        end;
                end;

                function obj = horzcat(obj1, varargin)
                        fprintf('1st arg is %s.\n', class(obj1));
                        if nargin > 1
                                fprintf('2nd arg is %s.\n', class(varargin{1}));
                        end;
                        obj = obj1; % Not important
                end;
        end;
end
```

Now, when testing this class with a small script:

```
% Please don't run this is you have valuable
% data in your base workspace.
clear classes;
clc;

a = A('dummy');
b = [-1, a]; % Should fail
```

the output is:

```
1st arg is double.
2nd arg is A.
```

This is surprising, because first argument is a double, i.e. the built-in `horzcat()` should have been called, subsequently throwing an exception about type mismatch or something. To my understanding, the type of the first argument decides which of the overloaded functions will be called (OK, we restrict ourselves to non-static methods). The code was tested on R2011b/Linux and R2012a/Windows, with the same results.

So, this is my question: what are the **actual** rules of calling overloaded methods? The Matlab documentation does not explain the above result, and I'd like to avoid developing code based on my illusions about how the language works.

Thank you in advance for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think MATLAB's documentation is pretty clear about it:

From [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/overloading-functions-for-your-class.html):

> MATLAB uses the dominant argument to determine which version of a
>   function to call. If the dominant argument is an object, then MATLAB
>   calls the method defined by the object's class, if there is one.

And from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/ordinary-methods.html) more about **dominant argument**:

> The dominant argument in a method's argument list determines which
>   version of the method or function that the MATLAB runtime calls.
>   Dominance is determined by the relative precedences of the classes of
>   the arguments. In general, *user-defined classes take precedence over
>   built-in MATLAB classes*. Therefore, the left most argument determines
>   which method to call. However, user-defined classes can specify the
>   relative dominance of specific classes.

Comment: Alright, that explains it clearly. Thanks for the time you took to answer me. (Note to myself: read carefully the documentation next time...)